# Hibernate load data on start up and make available for all user

Tags: java, hibernate

I have one table that has some important data like file uploading path, file path etc. Currently I am fetching all data at login time using hibernate and storing that objects in session and using them whenever and wherever i want. My question is, Is there any way so that i can fetch all data on server start up and make available that data for all user so that at login time i do not need to fire query in db. I am using struts 2.0 with hibernate.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but you could use a singleton service, @Service with Spring for example, then define a method @PostConstruct to load (calling the DAO layer) and store the data in a static map defined in the singleton and provide accessors to the map (using a Collections.unmodifiableMap)

Comment: +1 Used this exact approach to update a many-to-one property of an Entity inside a hibernate EventListener. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Create a ServletContextListener, which will be called when the application has been deployed, load the data in this listener, and store it in a singleton bean, or in the servlet context.